# Unexpected output in C (Traversal of Trees)

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, tree

I'm trying to code a program to go through a Tree in Breadth First Manner.

Here is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct TreeNode 
{
    struct TreeNode *right;
    struct TreeNode *left ;
    int    data;
};

struct TreeNode* newTreeNode(int data) 
{
    struct TreeNode* temp = (struct TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));

    temp->data = data;
    temp->right=NULL;
    temp->left=NULL;
    return temp;
}

struct QueueNode 
{
    struct QueueNode *next;
    struct TreeNode  *tree_element;
} *head,*tail;

void initQueue() 
{
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
}

void enQueue(struct TreeNode *ptr) 
{
    struct QueueNode *temp = (struct QueueNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueNode));

    if(head==NULL) 
        {
            temp->next=NULL;
            temp->tree_element = ptr;
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    else 
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
            temp->tree_element = ptr;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
}

struct QueueNode* deQueue() 
{
    struct QueueNode *temp = NULL;

    if(head==NULL) /*Empty Queue so return NULL*/
        {
            printf("Empty queue\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        return temp;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    struct QueueNode *temp = NULL;

    /* Initializing tree structure */
    struct TreeNode *root = newTreeNode(1);

    initQueue();
    enQueue(root); /* Root in the queue */

    temp = head;

    while(temp!=NULL) 
        {
            //printf("entering loop");
            temp = deQueue();
            if(temp==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Dequeue and Temp is NULL\n");
                    //break;
                }
            else if(temp!=NULL)
                {
                    if(temp->tree_element->left!=NULL)
                        {
                            enQueue(temp->tree_element->left) ;
                        }
                    if(temp->tree_element->right!=NULL)
                        {
                            enQueue(temp->tree_element->right);}
                }
            /*
              if(temp->tree_element!=NULL)*/
            if(temp==NULL)
                printf("Whatever\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
Empty queue

Dequeue and Temp is NULL

Whatever
```

My question is :

How do

```
Dequeue and Temp is NULL
```

**and**

```
Whatever
```

get printed at the same time. ***temp*** can't be NULL and !NULL at the same time right ?

Thank You

Comment: I appreciate whitespace in code, but here it is just distracting to the content.  Code indentations would also help with readability.

Comment: It appears that both prints are conditioned under `temp==NULL`

Comment: @iRove Agreed. Apologies

Comment: @Arun They're within different if constructs

Comment: Why are you assuming that `temp` is not null?

Comment: Time to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you have your two `printfs` under same condition:

```
  if(temp==NULL) //<---- temp == NULL condition
            {
                printf("Dequeue and Temp is NULL\n");
                //break;
            }
  else if(temp->tree_element->right!=NULL)
            {
                enQueue(temp->tree_element->right);} //<-- If you play little hide-n-seek with your beautifully aligned code you may find this hidden curly brace

        if(temp==NULL) //<---- Same condition
            printf("Whatever\n");
    }
```

Comment: Indentation. Should do more of that. Thanks a bunch!